# How to execute a task without blocking the rest of the program in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am currently working on the LIN Bus that is used in the automotive industry. I have to send to this Bus 5 information, each one takes 25ms to go and i have to put 60ms between each sending. I'm currently using a button to start a timer that run another timer to change each time the information and put the delay between them. The problem is that when i press the button i can't press again the button to stop the timer because the program is too busy.

My code:

```
    Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click

    If Start.Text = "START" Then
        Start.Text = "STOP"
        Timer6.Interval = 1000
        Timer6.Enabled = True
        Timer6.Start()
    ElseIf Start.Text = "STOP" Then
        Start.Text = "START"
        Timer6.Enabled = False
        Timer6.Stop()
    End If

End Sub

Dim auto As Integer = -1

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    auto += 1
    Select Case auto
        Case 0
            send("07")
        Case 1
            send("05")
        Case 2
            send("06")
        Case 3
            send("08")
        Case 4
            send("09")
    End Select
    If auto = 4 Then
        auto = -1
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Timer6_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer6.Tick
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Timer2.Interval = 100
    While n <> 5
        Timer2.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Start()
        n += 1
    End While
    If Start.Text = "STOP" Then
        Timer6.Interval = (freq.Text * 10 ^ 3)
        Timer6.Enabled = True
        Timer6.Start()
    ElseIf Start.Text = "START" Then
        Timer6.Enabled = False
        Timer6.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Do you have a solution so the program run and that i can stop sending information  when ever i want ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Look into multithreading or the Task Parallel Library (TPL).

Comment: I don't know if it's multithreading but placing a BackgroundWorker works great !

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` is a simplified wrapper for multithreading, so it is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into the BackgroundWorker, I don't have a working sample right now but that should point you to the right direction.

Comment: thank you for your message. I think that's what i'm looking for, i will work on it and come back to you !

Comment: I have used that a lot for a project years ago when I need a process running without freezing the form.

Comment: It's working great! I don't even need to use timer anymore. Thank you !